# Background of IndexOf equals 0 vs Substring equals

Tags: c#, substring, equality, indexof

I am writing a very simple method that returns a bool for whether or not a given string is located at position 0 of another string. When designing this I came up with 2 different designs that would do the same thing:

```
    private static bool IsAtPositionZeroV1(string stringToSearch, string stringToMatch)
    {
        if (stringToSearch.IndexOf(stringToMatch) == 0) return true;
        return false;
    }

    private static bool IsAtPositionZeroV2(string stringToSearch, string stringToMatch)
    {
        if (stringToSearch.Length >= stringToMatch.Length && stringToSearch.Substring(0, stringToMatch.Length) == stringToMatch) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

I am calling this function hundreds of thousands of times, so even a small difference in performance could be significant in the long run. I ran 100000 tests of both methods multiple times and found these results:

V1 (whether returning true or false) took about 30 - 40 ms to run 100,000 times.
V2 (whether returning true or false) took about 5 - 8 ms to run 100,000 times.

This really surprised me. What I had expected was V1 to be better if returning true, since it had less operations (no && in the if check) and V2 to do better if false, since V1 would seek the entire string trying to find a match whereas V2 would not.

Can someone explain why V2 is so much better across the board?

Thanks much!

Edit: per the comment below, I also tested string.StartsWith. This method came in 2nd place with an average of ~15 ms for 100,000 runs.

Comment: There is a string.StartsWith(string) method, btw..

Comment: ... well, now I feel dumb. Thanks @TaW

Comment: Well, since you already timing it, why not amend the question with the StartsWith results?

Comment: Btw: this `if( this.Length < value.Length) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    
                    return (TextInfo.CompareOrdinalIgnoreCaseEx(this, 0, value, 0, value.Length, value.Length) == 0);` seems to be a relevant part of the [c# source implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,23804789ea4c9c0e), so yes, the system also first compares the lengths.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd method is much more efficient because it contains 2 conditions with an `and` operand with the 1st condition: `stringToSearch.Length >= stringToMatch.Length` being much more efficiant than the 2nd condtion, since it uses the string length only, while the 2nd condition uses `string.Substring` which 
 loops throught the entire `string` length, one character at a time. Since there is an `and` operand between the 2 conditions, the 2nd condition is **not executed unless the 1st condition returns `true`**, hence the entire `if` clause becomes much more efficient.